# Android: failed to convert @drawable/picture into a drawable

Tags: android, image, android-layout, reference, drawable

In my drawable folder I have a few images and they all reference perfect, but when I try and add any more images with the exact same size in the same folder, and try to reference it, is flags up an error *"Failed to convert @drawable/picture into a drawable"*. I have tried the same image with a different name and it just keeps giving me that error. I have also tried it in a different XML layout and the same thing. Also the name of the picture have been "jack", "abc", "question_mark" as you can see there are strictly in the rules of the what characters you can use, and still the error message keeps coming up. Any advice would be great on how to fix the problem, thanks.

> Failed to convert @drawable/picture into a drawable

Comment: All sorted for some weird reason, suddenly after a few more clicks around it works! my advice if you get this problem is just to restart eclipse and make sure every thing is referenced and named correctly.

Comment: Sometimes just rebuilding the project from scratch help getting rid of these Android SDK problems. I've seen weird cases where it used wrong images for all my drawables (no error, but using the image next to the correct one for every drawable) probably a reference id problem.

Comment: again -1 Android, +1 Windows

Comment: For me it was the char "-" in the middle of the file name. After renaming everything went fine in Android Studio.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Restart Eclipse (unfortunately) and the problem will go away.

Comment: Closing and reopening the project in Eclipse worked for me. Thanks Aliyah!

Comment: Ia had this problem with drawable-normal-hdpi  but when having my images in drawable-hdpi  - everything is OK.

Comment: @DoctororDrive - perhaps your problem was slightly different. do you still have the error?

Comment: @Aliyah yes, it somehow related to the image. The real app wouldn't load it too. But there is nothing wrong with it. I tried storing it as jpg or png with no success. I'll think of something when I'll put my hands on it again.

Comment: pretty funny that this issue exists in both eclipse and android studio

Comment: @thgc so you can waste time with GC and other Objective-C problems that modern programming languages do for you?

Comment: @Eonasdan clearly you have never used Objective-C... ever heard of ARC?

Comment: closing/re-opening project did not work for me, but quitting/restarting android studio did work.  thank you Aliyah.

Comment: All I did in AS 2.1 was close the layout and reopen it again.

Answer (score 144):

Also check if the resource-name contains any illegal characters (for me it was a "-" in my-image)

Comment: Android's own icon pack contains filenames like 10-device-access-alarms.png, that Eclipse chokes on! Thanks.

Comment: Android studio also chokes on those filenames. Renaming to underscores fixed it for me.

Comment: For me it was the space character " "!

Comment: space was the culprit in my case

Comment: it was "-" for me as well, strangely android studio did not red marked this thing...

Answer (score 56):

If re-starting Eclipse does not correct the problem, make sure that the image name begins with an alpha character (non-numeric).

Comment: Thanks. Android create the drawable id variable in the R file with the drawable name. For example, if the file starts with a number the variable will start with a number and this is not allowed on Java language.

Comment: Also make sure it does not contain dashes (-); e.g. 'mic-back' is invalid, 'mic_back' is ok

Comment: This was my problem.  All the icons in [the pack](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) on Android's website have leading numbers.

Comment: Does it have to be a png?  I am trying to use jpg's.

Answer (score 28):

**`file name` must contain only `abc...xyz` `012...789`  `_` `.`  in Resources folder.**

**for ex:**

***my-image.png*** is `False`**!**
***MyImage.png***  is `False`**!**
***my image.png***  is `False`**!**
**...**
**...**

***my-xml.xml*** is `False`**!**
***MyXml.xml***  is `False`**!**
***my xml.xml***  is `False`**!**
**...**
**...**

Answer (score 25):

This is because your Image name contains "-" symbol . the only allowed characters are 
[a-zA-Z0-9_.]

Thanks

Comment: Uppercase letters are not valid. If you use them Android Studio will give this error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Invalid file name: must contain only lowercase letters and digits ([a-z0-9_.])

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem on Android Studio. No need to restart the IDE, just close and reopen the project and that will resolve the problem. (Make sure the src are correclty input).

Comment: Rebuilding the project will also do it.

Comment: I did File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... , which worked as well (and is probably overkill).

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio your resource(images) file name cannot start with `NUMERIC` and It cannot contain any `BIG` character. To solve your problem, do as Aliyah said. Just restart your IDE. This solved my problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify the name of your file, seems to be that any special characters in the file name makes it hiccup. for example chaange "my-main-header.png" to "header1.png" not sure why, but it works

Comment: That's because resource file names are converted to resource identifiers in `R.java` and `-` is not a valid char for identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

For Android Studio I had this same problem. It was caused by running from linux, meaning the files did not automatically receive an extension. By manually adding .png to the end of the filenames it could recognize the filetype and load accordingly.

Android studio might throw a hissy fit if you try to refactor rename inside the project, because android will try to regenerate R immediately. I do not know exactly what causes the error as it points to some seemingly random line of code, which in my case was a comment.

Solution to that: Delete from drawable, rename outside of the project and throw them in again.

Answer (score 1):

It can be even more trivial than what the other posters suggested: if you have multiple projects make sure you did not create the xml layout file in the wrong project.

After creation, the file will open automatically so this might go unnoticed and you assume it is in the correct project. Obviously any references to drawables or other resources will be invalid.

And yes, I am that stupid. I'll close any unused projects from now on :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a way to have it work without restarting Eclipse, or without closing project (it worked for me):

- rename image file name under res/ in Eclipse -> choose file and press F2 (for me it res/drawable-mdpi/bush-landscape.jpg  -> changed to bush.jpg)
- Build Project (it will still show error)
- change image where you used it (I changed in Graphical Layout. For me the place was LinearLayout/Background/bush-landscape  -> changed "bush-landscape" to "bush")
- Build Project

Answer (score 1):

My Image name was 21.jpg. I renamed it as abc.jpg and it worked. So Make sure your image name not starting with a number. However all above answers are also accepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the naming conventions right, then just go to **File** -> **Invalidate Caches / Restart..**

And press **Invalidate Caches / Restart..**

This helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had an image in different folders (with same name) for supporting different dpi and device sizes. All images had same name except one of them. It was mistyped and once I renamed it like other names, it resolved my issue.