# couldn't resolve resource drawable

Tags: android

[image]

Its error log says this I've read in this thread that you need to restart eclipse [Android: failed to convert @drawable/picture into a drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874262/android-failed-to-convert-drawable-picture-into-a-drawable) but it didn't work on me my project didn't run what could be the reason why it won't run? It has no problems just error log.

Comment: where is your drawable ? and what is that name ?

Comment: i have a png picture named rihanna and a couple of xml customized format gradient_bg gradient_bg_hover and a lot more but rihanna gets the error could it be bacause of file name?i read the he changed his name and it work let me try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you place the xml files under drawable folder??? If yes then try the following options. If not create a drawable folder under res and place the xml there.

1. Try clearn and rebuild the project

or

1. Restart you eclipse and rebuild the project.

Comment: yes all my drawable are placed in all 5 drawable folders clean and restart didnt work let me make sure coz ive made a few changes on its file name..

Answer (score 2):

Restart the Eclipse and the problem will go away.