# Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/backround.png

Tags: android

I was recently trying to learn Android development and I came into 2 problems. They are

```
Failed to convert @drawable/backround.png into a drawable
Couldn't resolve resource @drawable/backround.png
```

Heres My XML File

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backround.png"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >  
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

`Restart Eclipse` (unfortunately) and the problem will go away.

`(Android Studio: File --> Invalidate caches/Restart... )`

This question: [Android: failed to convert @drawable/picture into a drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874262/android-failed-to-convert-drawable-picture-into-a-drawable)

Answer (score 5):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/backround"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >  </LinearLayout>
```

There is no need of extensions here. just mention the name without extension

Answer (score 0):

replace **background.png** with **background**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backround"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
android:background="@drawable/backround.png"
```

with
`android:background="@drawable/backround"` and make sure that background image is present in your drawable folder