# How to use ImageView in the Design Editor of AndroidStudio?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-imageview

I'm working through the [Sunshine App tutorials](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1395568821/e-1647298625/m-1647298627) and am really stuck on putting an `ImageView` in my UI. Everything I've found has been doing it in the XML file and even those that I tried copying and pasting didn't work.

At first I had the ic_launcher only in the App Folder. Then after reading other solutions XML file I right clicked on `main/res/drawable` and did *New→Image Asset* so now all of those `mipmap-` contain the ic_launcher.png and it's still in my `app` as well, as you can see:

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio]

But now I've got no idea what to do for it to actually work. I tried a few things in the SRC, which seems to be where it goes:

- @mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher
- @drawable/ic_launcher
- ic_launcher
- @mipmap/ic_launcher

None have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are getting

> Failed to convert @drawable/... into a drawable

I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try restarting your Android studio.

[Android: failed to convert @drawable/picture into a drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874262/android-failed-to-convert-drawable-picture-into-a-drawable)