# Android Studio - Failed to convert @drawable/ into a drawable

Tags: android

I am getting this error when I am trying to use an image in Layout file:

```
Couldn't resolve resource @drawable
Failed to convert @drawable/image into a drawable
```

### Here is my layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I tried restart IDE, clean-rebuild but nothing, and I read all threads related to it ( I think ). 
**And yes my image name contains only [a-z0-9_.].**

Comment: what is the image name and extention?

Comment: @itzhar   the name is "image.png" but I tried to remove the extension, same error

Comment: @jlopez it doesn't contain any illegal as I mentioned in the question

Comment: im sure u see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874262/android-failed-to-convert-drawable-picture-into-a-drawable. anyway make sure u dont have any other file with same name

Comment: @itzhar yes I saw it, didn't work

Comment: try to use other image with different name

Comment: Itried it, Same error

Comment: Try changing the name of the image to other name that doesn't cause conflict with your app,sometimes Android Studio gets picky with names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way to avoid this

`RightClick` on `drawable` folder then `New` => `File` insert its name (myImage) 
  for example Then Select `Image Files`.

Then in `drawable` folder I replaced `myImage` file with the real image.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I solved it by renaming my image into something like : my_image.

Comment: As I said, the name of image is correct and I am still having this error

Comment: did you put any "_" in the name?, if not try to. sometimes Android studio gives problems for this kind of "stupid stuff".