# Android Studio xml not converting a png into a drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a rather weird problem, in my Android Studio's drawable project folder I have copied a .png material (from here https://design.google.com/icons/index.html#ic_settings_remote). I have named it `connect.png`. In the activity main I am referencing it the following way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"

    android:src="@drawable/connect.png" />
```

With the last line, ofc. It spits out 2 errors:
Can't resolve resource `"@android:drawable/connect.png"`
Failed to convert `"@android:@drawable/connect.png"`
What I've tried to fix this out:

1. restart the Android Studio
2. recopy the material resource in drawable folder
3. to go to Build->Clean project
   Neither of all those worked, I am looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: failed to convert @drawable/picture into a drawable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8874262/android-failed-to-convert-drawable-picture-into-a-drawable)

Comment: More specifically, the information you need is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19314797/5015207)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it (without `.png`):

```
android:src="@drawable/connect"
```

Comment: You are awesome, thank you soo much! It solved it, I will check your answer as a solution to the topic after 12 minutes because the system doesn't permit me to do it now. I was strictly sticking to a tutorial and probably the syntax used there was either incorrect or deprecated.  Thank you again!